# Disabling the timezone conversion in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, extjs4.2

When a JavaScript/ExtJS Date object is rendered, the date is always relative to the browser.

E.g the timestamp `4102338600000` would be rendered as '`Thu Dec 31 2099 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`' with IST zoned browser and will be one day less in EST zoned browser.

I tried couple of ways from the articles on the net like offsetting the timezone, etc but don't see straightforward option.

Our application needs uniform date, say in GMT/UTC/other format, irrespective of timezone.

In app code, 100's of places, below is used to render date :

```
format : 'd-M-Y',
```

Is there something to do the same thing but with UTC instead local conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString):

```
var date = new Date(4102338600000);
console.log(date.toUTCString());
"Wed, 30 Dec 2099 18:30:00 GMT"
```

**UPDATE**

[`Ext.Date.format`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-format) returns *local* date string representations, indeed. There does not seem to be an out-of-the-box way to make it return UTC dates. You can trick it this way though:

```
var ms2UTCDate = function(ms) {
    var date = new Date(ms);
    return new Date(date.valueOf() + 60000 * date.getTimezoneOffset());
}
console.log(Ext.Date.format(ms2UTCDate(4102338600000), 'Y-m-d'));
2099-12-30
```

That trick can be burned into `Ext.Date.format` as follows (don't do this unless you are sure you don't need the original behaviour!):

```
var originalExtDateFormat = Ext.Date.format;
Ext.Date.format = function(date, format) {
    if (date instanceof Date) {
        date = new Date(date.valueOf() + 60000 * date.getTimezoneOffset());
    }
    return originalExtDateFormat.call(this, date, format);
}
```

Comment: Hi Drake, updated the question with actual concern, pls advise.

Comment: Wonderful. This takes care of rendering it on screen scenario. Could you consider following one too and let me know the approach?   1. The date field is part of form 2. Each time we render it, it updates the value of the form and on save it goes back to server. 3. When tried to access the form again, it gets the updated one and not the original one, even without manual change.

Comment: LOL I won't let take triple advantage of a single Stackoverflow question, sorry :) Perhaps it's time to post another one.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could do below :

1. Send the timestamp to server along with the Timezone details.
2. On server side, based on the timezone, get the UTC date to save.
3. While retrieving, send the timezone as in requested params and have the date fetched accordingly for that.

Little lengthy, but should work  :-)