# How to add IST timezone object to Moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

I am referring to http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/

In example, its given for below locations :

```
moment.tz.add([
    'America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0',
    'America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0'
]);
```

I am not sure of IST values as its given for :

```
{
    name    : 'America/Los_Angeles',          // the unique identifier
    abbrs   : ['PDT', 'PST'],                 // the abbreviations
    untils  : [1414918800000, 1425808800000], // the timestamps in milliseconds
    offsets : [420, 480]                      // the offsets in minutes
}
```

Could someone help in adding IST object to this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The easiest way is to just use one of the files that includes time zone data from the [moment-timezone home page](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), such as `moment-timezone-2010-2020.js` or `moment-timezone-all-years.js` (or the minified versions).

You can however add just a single zone if you prefer.  You can find the zone's packed string within the data files listed above.  For India, the full zone definition is:

```
moment.tz.add("Asia/Calcutta|HMT BURT IST IST|-5R.k -6u -5u -6u|01232|-18LFR.k 1unn.k HB0 7zX0");
moment.tz.link("Asia/Calcutta|Asia/Kolkata");
```

You may or may not need the link, depending on what exactly you're doing.

Note that I assumed that by "IST" you mean India Standard Time, and not [Irish Standard Time or Israel Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).  Those zones would have different data, of course.

Also, since India has been on UTC+5:30 since 1942, you may just wish to use a fixed offset - which would eliminate the need to use moment-timezone.  Just use the `utcOffset` function in moment.  For example, both of the following will return the current time in India.

```
moment().utcOffset("+05:30").format()
```

or

```
moment().utcOffset(330).format()
```

Comment: Matt, could you also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267362/disabling-the-timezone-conversion-in-extjs/  ?    The above question was just for a workaround for that, I think there has to be some better way to do that.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know enough about ExtJS to answer that one, but I also don't see how it relates to this. If you have a UTC-based timestamp to begin with, just load that into moment with `moment.utc(timestamp)` and format it as desired.  No need to deal with time zone conversions.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint How do you get the value of 330 from +05:30 ?

Comment: @Rijo - `(5 * 60) + 30`  (5 hours, times 60 minutes in an hour, plus 30 minutes)