# Parsing GMT date string with moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I got the following input `Wed, 08 Feb 2017 10:09:19 GMT` form server.
I've been trying to parse this string with momentjs but couldn't find format that will parse the GMT right.

and if i'm not putting format at all then i got warning `value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date()`

Thanks!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355297/how-to-add-ist-timezone-object-to-moment-js

Answer (score 6):

Simply pass `format` paramter to moment constructor:

```js
var m = moment('Wed, 08 Feb 2017 10:09:19 GMT', 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss'); // Parse string in local time
console.log(m.format());
var mUtc = moment.utc('Wed, 08 Feb 2017 10:09:19 GMT', 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss'); // Parse string in UTC time
console.log(mUtc.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that by default moment parses and displays in local time, if you need UTC see [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/). If you need with multiple timezone use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Comment: looks like the date with timezone which is not GMT can not be parsed correctly. Consider this date 'February 4, 2020, 3:15:14 PM GMT-6'. Moment can't figure it out or I don't know how to find a way.