# Moment.js works for PDT but not for IST

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js library in my javascript code.

```
var lastActivity = moment(Date).valueOf();
```

The above code works fine and returns milliseconds when the time zone is PDT.

However, when the Date is in IST, I get the result as NaN.

```
var lastActivity = moment(new Date("Wed May 30 01:11:36 PDT 2018")).valueOf(); //works
var lastActivity = moment(new Date("Wed May 30 01:11:36 IST 2018")).valueOf(); //returns NaN
```

I read the moment.js documentation which says both the PDT and IST are same moment in time so the valueOf() should be the same for both.

```
From the moment.js documentation:
http://momentjs.com/docs/
var a = moment();
var b = moment.utc();
a.format();  // 2013-02-04T10:35:24-08:00
b.format();  // 2013-02-04T18:35:24+00:00
a.valueOf(); // 1360002924000
b.valueOf(); // 1360002924000
```

I tried changing using the .utc() method before .valueOf() but I still get the response as NaN for IST while it works good for PDT.

```
var lastActivity = moment(Date).utc().valueOf();
```

Comment: Can you put Example of `PDT` and `IST` and specify clearly where you are getting error and which one is working fine. Its bit confusing. Better to create working code snippet that would be easy to debug.

Comment: This might be  useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357618/1971908